# redirected deleted classic landing page "URL" to cloud page

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, landing-page, redirect, cloudpagesurl

it is possible a deleted classic landing page "URL" redirected to Cloud Page SFMC.

thanks

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? It’s hard to understand it as it is right now

Answer (score 2):

Once a page is deleted, you cannot set up redirects, etc. as you no longer have access to the page. I believe this is especially true with Classic pages as they have been (or in some cases are in the middle of) being sunset. Your only chance is to talk to Salesforce Support/Services and see if they can do anything, but I do get the feeling it is not possible.  If it were not deleted, but instead deactivated or otherwise paused, you would be able to do this I believe in the properties section.